# How to make a div remain at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, css, position

I would like to put a small tab at the bottom of the page for Contact Us- that should scroll as the page scrolls and should work in Older versions of IE also like IE 5.0. Please see the page at 
http://www.goshti.com/testcode.html

Any suggestions on how to solve this. I CSS or Javascript solution is both fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:fixed` on the element.

```
<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried position:fixed?
I'm not sure if it would work on older browsers tho.

You can wrap the bar within a relative div

```
#page-wrap { 
margin: 15px auto; 
position: relative; 
}

#bar {
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Oops my mobile internet is too slow @Samuel posted it first :)